# JUnit Servlets testing with jndi lookup for the datasource

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, jdbc, jndi

How to make unit test of servlets which uses jndi for lookup of datasource (JDBC) ?

Answer (score 3):

I run the following code in the before class method.

```
    try {

        // Create initial context
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, 
            "org.apache.naming");            
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

        ic.createSubcontext("java:");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

        // Construct DataSource
        OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ds.setURL(""); // <--insert url to database here
        ds.setUser("username"); //<-- self explanatory
        ds.setPassword("password"); //<-- self explanatory

        ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/examplename", ds); //<--insert name of binding here
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am using Tomcat as my server so I also had to reference the following jar files located in the tomcat\bin directory:

1. tomcat-juli.jar
2. bootstrap.jar
3. commons-daemon.jar

I hope this helps you

Comment: You saved me, this is what I needed to unit test a soap server's methods. Using postgres in my case give something like this:
  
`    import org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource;  
    // ...  
    PGPoolingDataSource ds = new PGPoolingDataSource();  
    ds.setDataSourceName("...");  
    ds.setServerName("...");  
    ds.setDatabaseName("...");  
    ds.setUser("...");  
    ds.setPassword("...");  
    ds.setMaxConnections(10);  
    ic.bind("...", ds);`

Answer (score 1):

Setup the JNDI context in your `@Before` (or `@BeforeClass`) methods, by manually creating the datasource.

(The answer is only guiding, but I can't provide anything concrete, since you haven't provided anything concrete)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you need JNDI then there is a simple standalone implementation which Can be used in applications and Unit tests scenarios.